# All keys in SharedPreferences return same value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using *Shared preferences* for the first time and getting errors. 
my **code** is like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 static final String ONE = ""; 
 static final String TWO = "";
 private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

SharedPreferences.Editor edi = mSharedPreferences.edit();
  edi.putString(ONE, "1");
  edi.putString(TWO, "2");
  edi.commit();

 String one = mSharedPreferences.getString(ONE,"1");
 String two = mSharedPreferences.getString(TWO,"2");
 System.out.println("Your Numbers: "one+ "   " + two);
 }
 }
```

Expected Output:

```
 Your Numbers:  1   2
```

Console Output:

```
 Your Numbers:  2   2
```

I can't figure out what i am doing wrong in it. Share your views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add some string to the names/keys. Currently **both key names are blank** and hence your code is overwriting the same preference value
.
Change the static strings as follows and it should work fine.

```
static final String ONE = "one"; 
static final String TWO = "two";
```

**Also try using a helper class** to make things simpler with shared preferences. Here is one that i wrote: [Android-SharedPreferences-Helper](https://github.com/viralypatel/Android-SharedPreferences-Helper)

Comment: but if they were overriding the value then the output would be like "Your Numbers:     " i.e null according to my case.

Comment: in your `putString` method the first parameter is the key name. Second parameter is the value. So you are first assing alue `1` to key <blank> and then assigning value 2 the same key <blank>. then in get string you are getting the value of the key <blank> twice, which is now `2`. That's why you see `2` printed twice.

Comment: its working but I don't understand as I am having 2 keys here.

Comment: you have two variables not keys. the value in variable will become the key. right now the value in both String variables is "" (blank) so same key. you need to have unique values in each string which forms a key.

Answer (score 3):

Because of this:

```
static final String ONE = ""; 
static final String TWO = "";
```

change it to:

```
static final String ONE = "One"; 
static final String TWO = "Two";
```

U need unique values for every preference.
In your case the ONE gets overridden by the TWO.

**Extra info**

If u look in the android docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) you will see that `putString` requires two parameters:

- `key      : String: The name of the preference to modify.`
- `value    : String: The new value for the preference.`

and if u than look at `getString` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) you will notice that it also has two parameters, both the same as `putString`:

- `key      : String: The name of the preference to retrieve.`  **-- important**
- `defValue : String: Value to return if this preference does not exist.`

The **name/key** is the part that let the `get` part know from which preference it needs to get the value.

Hope this will make things a bit clearer for u!

Comment: you mean if i put same value in two keys then I would get this error?

Comment: Yes, correct, every preference has it's own unique **key** and it's own value. If u use the same key, than the last one will override the previous preference. for more information check this [SharedPreferences.Editor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

Both the strings are empty

```
static final String ONE = ""; 
static final String TWO = "";
```

It should be like :

```
static final String ONE = "one"; 
static final String TWO = "two";
```

Comment: whats the difference ,if  I provide the value later ?

Comment: The values can be added later but keys have to be defined because shared preference searches the key u want the value for.

Comment: You can use this library with single class for better preferences management: @https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo